# Python pytest Exclude Test Directory in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pytest, pythonpath

I have a weird scenario with `pytest` where we need to exclude the test directory from `PYTHONPATH` during the test.

**Context**

The pytest command for reference

`python -m pytest main_project_a/folder_a/sub_project_a ...`

I have `main_project_a` that requires to run test with a custom build of Python. It is built in the `build` folder. I need to use it to run the test in `folder_a/sub_project_a`. But modules in `sub_project_a` requires another package `api_2`, but `pytest` includes the *test directory* `main_project_a/folder_a/sub_project_a` in the `PYTHONPATH`, so it tried to look for `api_2` in the *test directory*, which doesn't exist.

How to tell `pytest` no to include the test directory, or tell `pytest` to look in `main_project_a/build/sub_project_a/lib/python3.9/sub_project_a` instead?

```
WORKSPACE
- main_project_a
    - ...
    - build
        - sub_project_a
            - bin
            - lib
                - python3.9
                    - sub_project_a
                        - api
                        - api_2
            - ...
    - folder_a
        - sub_project_a
            - api
                - module_a
                    - test
                - module_b
                    - test
```

Comment: add test_ prefix to it

Comment: @Magaren, can you elaborate?

Comment: still need help?

Comment: hi @Magaren, i actually did not find a good solution for it after trying multiple scenarios and workaround, we ended up deciding to take the effort and rename the folder and update the references